# Can you customize the automatic permalink population on new posts?

Tags: permalinks, javascript, wp-admin

I have a custom post type for events, I would love to intercept/change the JavaScript that populates the title to the permalink to have it also also use the date custom field (ACF) I have. Does anyone happen to know how to do this? (Or at least the area to look in? I am versed in JS, just not the WordPress admin's secrets.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) hook. and then add a custom rewrite rule to your `register_post_type` function:

```
function replace_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    $post_type = get_post_type( $id );

    if( is_object( $post ) && $post_type == 'events' ){
        $custom_date = get_field('YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD');
        return str_replace( '%custom_date%' , $custom_date, $post_link );
    }
 
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'replace_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

and add to `register_post_type`:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'events/%custom_date%', 'with_front' => false )
```

**make sure to flush your rewrite rules when you are done by going to: Settings > Permalinks and clicking 'save changes'**

Comment: Hmm, I was really hoping to intercept the JavaScript that generates the initial permalink, just so I could leave the ability to manually modify them intact. I assume this hook is going to change the slug on save?

Comment: correct. its the correct way to do with wordpress.